# Not able to ping PC connected with Ethernet cable

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, windows-11

On my local network, I have a PC and a laptop. My pc has windows 10 pro, and my laptop has windows 11 pro installed. Recently I set up file sharing and remote desktop on my local network, my goal is to connect to the PC from my laptop.

When my pc is connected to the modem via LAN cable, I cannot ping it from my laptop when the laptop is also connected to the modem with LAN cable, but when I disable ethernet on my laptop and connect with WIFI, I'm able to ping the PC.
The odd thing is that when I connect the PC to the modem over WIFI and disable Ethernet, I'm able to ping it from my laptop whether it's connected through WIFI or LAN. I have a laptop with windows 10 pro installed, and everything works fine whether Lan or WIFI. So I suppose the source of the problem is not in my modem, which I also checked and there's no MAC filtering on it. So it's safe to say that the issue is with the windows 11 itself. I tried to google the issue, and found bunch of solution that neither of them worked in my case, but I list them here here so you could see what I have done so far:

1. the drivers for the laptop are all up to date, I tried to uninstall modem drive and let the windows figure out the correct driver and it didn't work, I also downloaded the drivers manually both from the Dell and Intel websites and they didn't work as well.
2. The network is set to be private, DHCP is set to autoconfigured, I also checked with setting manual static IP on both machines and it still didn't work, disabling IPv6 on my laptop didn't work as well.
3. I'm using Bitdefender total security, I disabled everything and didn't work. Also booted in safe mode and still didn't work.
4. reset network settings with these commands and didn't work as well:

   ```
   ipconfig /flushdns
   ipconfig /renew
   nbtstat –R
   nbtstat –RR
   netsh int ip reset
   c:\resetlog.txt
   netsh winsock reset
   ```
5. I tested with different ethernet cables and even used different ports on the modem, and noting change. I believe it's not a cable problem, because the same Ethernet cable works totally fine when I connect it to my windows 10 laptop.

And here's a screenshot of network sharing options on both machines:

[network sharing options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpQ3W.jpg)

At the end I contacted Microsoft support and they suggested to downgrade to windows 10 and wait for the official release of windows 11, Since it takes a lot time to reinstall everything, I preferer to make it work on my current install and I'm open to any suggestion.
Sorry for the long post and thank you all in advance.

Comment: Provide screenshots of the network sharing options you have enabled/disabled for both machines as an [edit] to your question

Comment: I assume you tried rebooting both computers?

Comment: @Ramhound attached the screenshot, is there anything else you might think of that I didn't include in my question?

Comment: @user253751 yes I have restarted both systems and even turned them of many times so far

Comment: You will want to turn on Network Discovery.  However, are you 100% both devices, are part of the same subnet?

Comment: @Ramhound Network discovery was turned on for private networks, I also turned it on for "Guest or Public" as well, but didn't solve the issue, and I checked the subnet mask, it's 255.255.255.0 on both machines

Comment: I didn’t ask for the subnet mask, I asked if both machines, were part of the same subnet.

Comment: @Ramhound how do I check for that? both machines are on the same network and the respected ips are 192.168.1.4 & 192.168.1.6

Comment: 192.168.1.x is the subnet, 192.168.1.4 (.6) is the address of the machine while connected to the ethernet adapter (i.e. whatever configuration is not working the way you are expecting).

Comment: Have you tried removing the modem/router in question and directly connecting 2 PCs with LAN cable? Assign static IPs to both. One say 192.168.1.2 and other say 192.168.1.3. Now test again disabling all firewalls. Does your modem/router has DD-WRT flashed instead of stock firmware?

Answer (score 0):

Try running something like arp -a to get a list of all devices on the network IP addresses, maybe when you switch ethernet adapters the IP of the device changes to a subnet you can't see? If you can see the device on the same network that way you should be good to go.

Comment: I did what you said and I can see other IPs and I can ping them as well, but my PC isn't one of them and doesn't show up in the list